# 407 (Proxy Authentication Required) - APIRest Laravel/Angular

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, angular

estoy realizando una APIRest con Laravel 6 y Angular. Al enviar un registro al servidor, para dar de alta un usuario, el servidor me devuelve el error 407 Proxy Authentication Required.

En mi local el registro anda bien, pero en producción tengo este problema, investigando encontre que debo agregar un header pero no se cual ni que valor darle.

Dejo una captura del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo el código de la función register que se encargar del registro del nuevo usuario:

```
public function register(Request $request){

    //Recoger los datos del usuario por POST
    $json = $request->input('json', null);
    $params = json_decode($json);               //Object
    $params_array = json_decode($json, true);   //Array

    if(!empty($params) && !empty($params_array)){
        // Limpiar datos
        $params_array = array_map('trim', $params_array);

        //Validar los datos
        $validate = \Validator::make($params_array, [
            'name' => 'required|alpha',
            'surname' => 'required|alpha|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($validate->fails()){
            //La validacion ha fallado

            $data = array(
                'status' => 'error',
                'code'   => 404,
                'message' => 'El usuario no se ha creado',
                'errors' => $validate->errors()
            );
        }else{
            //La validacion ha pasado correctamente

            //Cifrar la contraseña
            $pwd = hash('sha256', $params->password);

            //Crear el usuario

            $user = new User();
            $user->name = $params_array['name'];
            $user->surname = $params_array['surname'];
            $user->email = $params_array['email'];
            $user->password = $pwd;
            $user->role = 'ROLE_USER';

            //Guardar el usuario

            $user->save(); //Realiza el INSERT en la base de datos

            $data = array(
                'status' => 'success',
                'code'   => 200,
                'message' => 'El usuario se ha creado',
                'user' => $user
            );
        }
    }else{
        $data = array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'code'   => 404,
            'message' => 'Faltan datos'
        );
    }
```

Y adjunto las cabeceras que tengo en el index.php para evitar conflictos con las políticas CORS, por si se genera aca el problema:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if($method == "OPTIONS") {
    die();
}
```

Comment: En teoría en los ajax se podrían agregar estos headers, pero es una anomalía, no es la forma en la que se usan los proxies habitualmente, para mí hay otro tipo de error, y la manifestación es que termina bloqueandolo el proxy. Primero intentá acceder a la API con el navegador a ver que pasa.

Comment: Es decir, el proxy debería enviarlo el navegador.

Comment: Hola Emeeus, realice la consulta a través de postman y tuve el mismo error, relei el código y no encontré errores, por eso edite la pregunta y añadir el código de registro y un par de cabeceras que tengo en el index.php por las dudas que allí se genere el error

Comment: Yo creo que antes de probar otra cosa, deberías poner las credenciales del proxy en el navegador y/o en Postman y ver que sucede. Si funciona no hay problema con ningún código. Si la idea es que los usuarios **no** tengan que poner un proxy, tienes que revisar que es lo que sucede en el server en donde esta hosteada la API o en la red, osea ver porque solicita un proxy.  Si los futuros usuarios usan proxy no tendrás de que preocuparte.

Comment: Emeeus, gracias por responder, con credenciales te referis a los campos que forman el registro del  usuario? si es así, ya realice la prueba y tuve nuevamente el error 407

Comment: No, no, las credenciales del proxy.

Comment: Donde saco estas credenciales?

Comment: Bueno si no estas al tanto de la existencia de un proxy, es un problema. Que pasa si a la API en producción querés acceder con el navegador?

Comment: si accedo directamente a la URL de la API no hay ningún error, el problema esta cuando hago una solicitud POST a api/register

Comment: Que raro eso, lo único puedo pensar que podría ser es un tema con CORS. Lo que podrías hacer es armar un ejemplo minimo, esto es: hacer un metodo mínimo en el backend , solo con el header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'` y retornando un string. Y en el ajax solo un `fetch` GET